# How to use ASP.NET Core SignalR with Pace.js

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-signalr

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC project that has HTTPS enabled and targets Docker Linux containers.  I have followed all the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio to enable SignalR in my project.

When the project is run I see the following SignalR-related log entries:

```
[2019-02-19T15:20:14.395Z] Information: Normalizing '/mainHub' to 'https://localhost:44392/mainHub'. Utils.ts:185:30

[2019-02-19T15:20:14.858Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://localhost:44392/mainHub?id=3RS_UsO7L20SQHgW4meRpQ. Utils.ts:185:30

WebSocket is not in the OPEN state insys-signalr-location.min.js:1:426

[2019-02-19T15:33:41.840Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 ().'. Utils.ts:179:21

Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 (). WebSocketTransport.ts:130:16
```

Is there anything in particular I need to do to use SignalR with pace.js?

EDIT

Initially I thought this was a problem with Docker.  After identifying the conflict with pace.js I reframed the question.

Comment: I've got a colleague who has worked on a similar project which uses SignalR with Docker / .Net Core.  It definitely works, afraid I haven't seen this specific problem and it's hard to diagnose without more detail.

Comment: I wonder if you're colleague would be willing to share an example DockerFile for one of their projects.  I'm a total newb to Docker.  I'm not *certain* that this is a Docker configuration issue, but I suspect it is at this point.

Comment: Afraid it's all closed source :(.  Does your code work if you debug it outside of Docker containers?  If so, I strongly suspect it's to do with your docker network/ports.  The easiest way to start with this is to map docker ports to your localhost to let them communicate.  See https://medium.freecodecamp.org/expose-vs-publish-docker-port-commands-explained-simply-434593dbc9a3

Comment: Have you exposed the desired ports in the Dockerfile ?

Comment: 443 and 80 are exposed in the Dockerfile.  Are there other ports that should be exposed?

Comment: @Phil S - good idea... I ran in IIS Express and got the same error... so not looking like a docker problem afterall.

Comment: Turns out pace.js was blocking/using the socket.  As soon the reference to pace was removed, it all worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that this was a conflict with pace.js.  Running the following script before loading pace.js solved the problem:

```
<script>
    window.paceOptions = { ajax: { ignoreURLs: ['mainHub', '__browserLink', 'browserLinkSignalR'], trackWebSockets: false } }
</script>
```