# WebSocket is not in the OPEN state

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I'm trying SignalR on ASP.NET Core. It works fine running from VisaulStudio debugger.

However it does not work in deployed code, showing the error message "WebSocket is not in the OPEN state" and "Handshake was canceled". What is the possible cause of the problem?

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.2.0
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR 1.1.0
- @aspnet/signalr 1.1.2
- Bootstrap4
- jQuery v3.1.0
- Kestrel
- No HTTPS SSL
- Tried with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 18.4

Network Console on Google Chrome

```
WebSocket is not in the OPEN state (kms-event-exit.js:12)
Uncaught Error: Seerver returned handshake error: Handshake was canceled. (signalr.min.js:16)
 at HubConnection.processHandshakeResponse (signalr.min.js:16)
 at HubConnection.processIncomingData (signalr.min.js:16)
 at WebSocketTransport.HubConnection.connection.onreceive (signalr.min.js:16)
 at WebSocket.webSocket.onmessag (signalr.min.js:16)
[2019-04-06T01:06:41.965Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned handshake error: Handshake was canceled.'. signalr.min.js:16
Uncaught (in promise) Server returned handshake error: Handshake was canceled. (signalr.min.js:16)
```

Startup functions.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddRazorOptions(options => options.AllowRecompilingViewsOnFileChange = true);

        services.AddSignalR(options => options.EnableDetailedErrors = true);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Main");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<Hubs.KmsHub>("/KmsHub");
            routes.MapHub<Hubs.AllResetHub>("/AllResetHub");
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areaDefault",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Main}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Main}/{id?}/{exit?}");
        });
    }
```

Logs

```
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.HttpConnectionDispatcher[4]
      Establishing new connection.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionHandler[5]
      OnConnectedAsync started.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.Transports.WebSocketsTransport[1]
      Socket opened using Sub-Protocol: '(null)'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/favicon.ico
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/favicon.ico'. Physical path: 'D:\K4\KMS\KMS\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\publish\wwwroot\favicon.ico'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 6.664ms 200 image/x-icon
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/lib/Popper/popper.min.js.map
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 3.4573ms 404
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js.map
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/lib/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.min.js.map
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 2.3443ms 404
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js.map'. Physical path: 'D:\K4\KMS\KMS\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\publish\wwwroot\lib\boo
tstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js.map'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 114.858ms 200 text/plain
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css.map
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css.map'. Physical path: 'D:\K4\KMS\KMS\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\publish\wwwroot\lib\b
ootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css.map'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 18.0356ms 200 text/plain
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext[2]
      Handshake was canceled.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.Transports.WebSocketsTransport[7]
      Waiting for the client to close the socket.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.Transports.WebSocketsTransport[2]
      Socket closed.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Internal.HttpConnectionManager[2]
      Removing connection 8K2CDgDs6jWXM7DPMWk_Dg from the list of connections.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 15047.5227ms 101
```

JavaScript code which caught the exception.

```
function kmsEventExit(url) {
    var exitButton = document.getElementById("exitButton");
    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(url + "/KmsHub").build();

    //Disable send button until connection is established
    exitButton.disabled = true;

    //Wait until connection finishes.
    connection.start().then(function () {
        exitButton.disabled = false;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());   //WebSocket is not in the OPEN state
    });

    //Call ExitKms on clicking the button.
    exitButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        connection.invoke("ExitKms").catch(function (err) {
            return console.error(err.toString());
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    //Catch the result.
    connection.on("ExitKmsResult", function (isAlert, options) {
        if (isAlert) {
            swal(JSON.parse(options));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have identified the problem!

It did not work because pace.js was not compatible with signalr.js. WebSocket variable was duplicated in these two plugins. SignalR works fine after removing pace.js.

SignalR on VisualStudio worked with pace.js because it uses SSE and IIS Express, instead of WebSocket and Kestrel, thus pace.js and signalr.js can be compatible with this particular configuration.

Reference:
https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2389

Comment: Why pace.js is not fixing this?

Comment: wow thank you for sharing this; I installed a template that used pace, which I've never heard of, and if I hadn't found this reply I probably would have lost my mind trying to understand why it just stopped working! thanks!

Answer (score 16):

There has been an workaround posted in a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2389#issuecomment-393760284) that has worked for me.

Before connecting, add:

```js
Object.defineProperty(WebSocket, 'OPEN', { value: 1, });
```

*Using this method, there's no need to remove pace.js.*

---

**Important note:** if you are using Blazor Server, you will face the same issue. Remove pace.js then, as it's quite useless in this case.

Comment: Thanks! you saved me hours of debug

Comment: Same. you saved my time. tnx

Answer (score 2):

As Identified above, pace and signalr are not directly compatible, however putting the script below before loading pace.js will resolve the problem instead of outrightly remove pace.js

```
<script>
            window.paceOptions = { ajax: { ignoreURLs: ['mainHub', '__browserLink', 'browserLinkSignalR'], trackWebSockets: false } }
        </script>
```

[Reference to above answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54770354/how-to-use-asp-net-core-signalr-with-pace-js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54772440)

The value of 'mainHub' is the signalR hub in your C# application you are connecting to.